# Install mysql-workbench failed: Requires: proj, tinyxml, python-paramiko >= 1.15.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, centos-7

I am installing mysql-workbench to migrate Postgres database to Mysql.

> OS System Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

I am installing mysql-workbench and follow these instructions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html

I have the following repo.

```
repo id                                                                                  repo name                                                                                               status
cloudera-manager                                                                         Cloudera Manager, Version 5.7.5                                                                              7
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64                                                        MySQL Connectors Community                                                                                  30
mysql-tools-community/x86_64                                                             MySQL Tools Community                                                                                       40
mysql57-community/x86_64                                                                 MySQL 5.7 Community Server                                                                                 164
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64                                                Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7                                              6
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)                                                                13,573
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common/7Server/x86_64                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (RPMs)                                                         209
repolist: 14,029
```

When I tried the command

```
sudo yum -y install mysql-workbench-community
```

I got the these erros.

```
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-tools-community)
           Requires: proj
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-tools-community)
           Requires: tinyxml
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-tools-community)
           Requires: python-paramiko >= 1.15.1
```

My question is how to find the repo of these dependencies package - proj, tinyxml, python-paramiko?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably better suited for either [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com) “_Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment._” or [**Unix & Linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com) “_Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems._”

Comment: @hot2use I disagree - databases and their attendant tools are on topic here. To the OP, I would say that Workbench is notorious for its dependencies - just try to install from source! :-) Try yum grouplist and there should be something like "Development Workstation and Creative.." (from memory) - do a sudo yum groupinstall "Deve...." and then try again. If this still leaves dependencies, search for stuff like python-paramiko &c. and either use an rpm or install from source. For fedora, it's nearly always something like sudo yum install library_name`-devel`.

Answer (score 1):

You need install additional packages:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install proj
sudo yum install tinyxml
sudo yum install libzip
```

if You have trouble with repo

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install epel-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

than

```
sudo yum -y install mysql-workbench-community
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there is a correct repo exist, these packages will be installed automatically. All these conveniences only happen when there is right repository exists. However, I don't know what repo provides these packages.

Comment: at least on my copies RHEL and CentOS it run as described, if You can not find information what is it EPEL - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL, wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 0):

> Requires: python-paramiko >= 1.15.1

[Download](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-unsupported-x86_64/python-paramiko-1.15.1-1.sdl7.noarch.rpm.html) `python-paramiko-1.15.1-1.sdl7.noarch.rpm` then install:

```
rpm -ivh python-paramiko-1.15.1-1.sdl7.noarch.rpm
```

If when installing `python-paramiko` you get:

> error: Failed dependencies:
>           python-ecdsa is needed by python-paramiko-1.15.1-1.sdl7.noarch

```
yum install -y python-ecdsa
```

Then you can install `mysql-workbench`:

```
yum -y install mysql-workbench-community
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dependencies below

```bash
sudo dnf install -y https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/proj-data-9.0.1-1.fc37.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install -y https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/proj-9.0.1-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf install mysql-workbench-community-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm
```

Regards